# r equivalent of matlab eval

Tags: r, eval

**Background:**
MatLab (or MATLAB) has a command called "eval".  It allows text based construction of statements and their execution.
this code:

```
x = 1:100
y = sin(x*(pi/50))

f1 = 'plot('
f2 = 'x,y'
f3 = ');'

eval(strcat(f1,f2,f3))
```

will create this plot

[image: plot]

The help documentation in 'R' seems to not be about specifying and manipulating character strings.

**Question:**
What is the way to do that in 'R'

Comment: I guess you are looking for this `plot(x,y, type = "l")`

Comment: @lizzie, I think MichaelChirico got it.  I want to be able to wrap it in loops, and build variable names and function parameters using variables.

Answer (score 3):

You want `eval(parse())`, e.g.,

```
eval(parse(text = paste0("plot(", "x,y", ")")))
```

Of course you'll have to build on this command to truly mimic the MATLAB output, e.g.

```
arguments <- c('x', 'y', 'type="l"', 'col="blue"',
               'xlim=range(x)','ylim=range(y)')
cmd <- paste0("plot(", paste(arguments, collapse = ","), ")")
eval(parse(text = cmd))
```

[image]

Comment: `eval(call('plot',as.symbol('x'),as.symbol('y')))` rather than building up the properly delimited textual representation only to parse it back.